# where is the kernel-parameters.txt directory?

Tags: kernel

I'm now see a tutorial that open `kernel-parameters.txt` in terminal using this command first:

```
cd Documentation/
```

and then :

```
view kernel-parameters.txt
```

Tutorial distro is CentOS but I'm using Ubuntu. When I ever try change directory to Documentation I get error:

> No such file or directory

how can I see kernel parameters txt file ? Actually where is it?

Answer (score 3):

The file Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt is in the Linux source repository, for example, clone the main Linux git repo:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux
cd linux
less Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt
```

Alternatively, one can view this via the URL from the git repo: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt

Mind you, that applies to the latest upstream kernel, to see the same file for the different Ubuntu Linux kernels, one needs to look at them at the Ubuntu gitweb, for example, Xenial: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/ubuntu/ubuntu-xenial.git/tree/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt

Comment: how can i put the directory into terminal ?